# Is a paste a type of glue?

Tags: phase-transition, adhesion

I just wanted to know the answer to this because of the idea of phases of matter, would a paste (or glue) drying count as a change between the states of solid and liquid?

Comment: Beware not to confuse element with compound though!  And by the way... how would you call nutella? solid or liquid?

Comment: It's a very good question! What could you study about the physics of a glue?

Comment: the glue normally works via adhesion mechanical or dispersive... whether you call something solid or liquid i think is a matter of timescale.

Comment: @PietroOliva, [Nutella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutella#Ingredients) is a somewhat complicated mixture of things. I'm guessing that it probably is a [colloidal suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid) of various fine, solid-like particles in a solution of liquid-y ingredients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When paste or glue "dries" it is actually undergoing a chemical reaction so this is not a phase transition as in the phases matter.  Many chemical reactions may start with compounds in one state that change to another; examples are fire, precipitates in solution, cement etc....